# Error Checking using Func Delegate

Tags: c#, linq, delegates, lambda

So i recently learned this new trick of using Func Delegate and Lambda expression to avoid multiple validation if statements in my code.

So the code looks like something like

```
 public static void SetParameters(Dictionary<string,object> param)
        {
            Func<Dictionary<string, object>, bool>[] eval = 
            {
                e => e != null ,
                e => e.Count ==2 ,
                e  => e.ContainsKey("Star"),
                e  => e.ContainsKey("Wars")
            };

            var isValid = eval.All(rule => rule(param));

            Console.WriteLine(isValid.ToString());
        }
```

but my next step is i would like to do some error checking as well. So for e.g. if the count !=2 in my previous example i would like to write build some error collection for more clear exception further down.

So i been Wondering how can i achieve that using similar Func and Lamdba notation ?.

I did come up with my rules checker class

```
public class RuleChecker
    {
        public Dictionary<string, object> DictParam
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string ErrorMessage
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

Can someone help as how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

you can do this:

```
        List<string> errors = new List<string>();
        Func<Dictionary<string, object>, bool>[] eval = 
        {
            e => { bool ret = e != null; if (!ret) errors.Add("Null"); return ret; },
```

However a more elegant solution would be to

```
        List<string> errors = new List<string>();
        Func<bool, string, List<string>, bool> EvaluateWithError = (test, message, collection) =>
        {
            if (!test) collection.Add(message); return test;
        };

        Func<Dictionary<string, object>, bool>[] eval = 
        {
            e => EvaluateWithError(e != null, "Null", errors),
```

Comment: Nice.  But shouldn't that be (!test) in the second solution?

Comment: Thanks Preet, that works. But i am wondering if there is a much more generic way like EvaluteWithError Delegate rather a class and i can reuse it rather creating the Func<...> everytime in every class ?.

Comment: you could just create a static class with a static method to encapsulate it.